# Passing a Command as a Variable to another Program?

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I'm creating an interactive script that allows me to plot specific parts of a data file using Gnuplot. These files contain multiple channels of instrumentation data and I'd like to plot specified channels together on the plot. At the moment I can only plot each channel independently with a script.

```
for ycolumn in $ycolumns; do 

    gnuplot -p << EOF
    set datafile separator ","
    set autoscale
    set grid
    set xlabel "Time"
    set ylabel "Data"
    set title "$graphTitle"
    plot "$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn lt rgb "red" with lines t " "
    EOF
```

This is the code that plots each channel independently. To plot them together I need the the plot line to look like this

```
plot "$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn1 lt with lines t " ","$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn2 lt with lines t " ", etc...
```

My question is how, if possible, could I have a for loop outside gnuplot that appends each column command ("$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn1 lt with lines t " ") to a variable, and then that variable gets passed to the plot command inside Gnuplot?

I was thinking about using expect but I can't figure out a way to implement that in the way I'm trying to automate this script.

Comment: From the bash point of view, the entire here document is just a string. You can totally have `myplotcommand='plot "whatever" foo bar'` and then have a line in your here document that just says `$myplotcommand`. Alternatively, you can generate and write any plot commands you want to a temp file and then have gnuplot plot it

Comment: Note that you can use the special file `''` to re-use that last filename.

Comment: So either I'm misunderstanding how what you've written is implemented or Gnuplot won't accept it, but when I create a variable like 
'myplotcommand = ' plot "$filename" using $xcolumn: ...'
and then where I would use the plot, I just put
'$myplotcommand' 
Gnuplot kicks me out saying there is no such command. I am still pretty new to scripting so am I missing some context as to how I should represent that and pass it in as a Gnuplot command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward approach is to first assemble the entire plot command (as mentioned in the comments by 'that other guy') and then use it in the here document:

```
plotCmd=""
plotCmdDelim="plot"
for ycolumn in $ycolumns
do
    plotCmd="${plotCmd}${plotCmdDelim} '${FILE}' using $xcolumn:$ycolumn lt rgb 'red' with lines t ' '"
    plotCmdDelim=","
done

gnuplot -p << EOF
set datafile separator ","
set autoscale
set grid
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Data"
set title "$graphTitle"
${plotCmd}
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! It took a little finagling but it worked. I have never had to use the curly braces before with a parameter so I was unaware that they could be used like that. Guess I should be doing a little more reading.